# How to extract text from contenteditable div (but not html tags)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <div contenteditable type="text" id="inputEmailTo" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipients"></div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).on('keyup', '#inputEmailTo', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log($(this).text());
      var recipient = $(this).text(); // How can I extract just the text and not any appended <span>s
      $(this).text(''); // And how can I remove them
      $(this).append('<span class="recipient">'+recipient+'</span>');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Ignoring the random type="text" and placeholder because it used to be an `<input>` and I might end up changing it back - I am looking to 'transform' (for lack of a better word) the text in a contenteditable div into an html element within the div every time the enter key is pressed.

What I'm really trying to achieve is functionality similar to the GMail recipients list.

I am entirely convinced that there is a better way to do it - definitely open to suggestions. However I am still curious about the question as per specified in the title.

**Other Ideas**

I also considered having the extra elements appended as a sibling to an `<input>` element and using css to style them such that the extra elements are superimposed on the input field and then dynamically adjusting the `padding-left` attribute of the input box.

Sorry this post is a bit of a mess with essentially two questions clumped together - how should I ask these on stackoverflow? Should they be two separate questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this counts as an answer (because you suggested it anyway), but I'd recommend that you place the "finalized" email addresses in their own boxes outside of your editable div and adjust the padding/margin/position of the editable one as necessary (that's what GMail does, too). Then you don't have to worry about ignoring the elements you've already added and only extracting the new text; they are already separate.

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <div id="finalizedAddresses"></div>
  <div contenteditable type="text" id="inputEmailTo" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipients"></div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#inputEmailTo', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).text());
    var recipient = $(this).text();
    $(this).text('');
    $('#finalizedAddresses').append('<span class="recipient">'+recipient+'</span>');
  }
});
```

Comment: `(that's what GMail does, too)` thanks, that's reassuring. I guess I was just hoping to avoid all that (messy imo) css.

Comment: Cool things can be hard and messy. :) something you could try would be to make all of the elements `float:left` and then make your editable div `width:1px; overflow:visible` which might make it easier. On the other hand, it might be hard for users to click in the 1px wide div. :P

Comment: If I do do it this way, I would probably go back to an input rather than a contenteditable div. The only reason I tried the div was because it could have child elements. Could you explain the reasoning behind `width: 1px; overflow: visible` though?

Comment: Basically what I was thinking (didn't test) was that as you fill up the line, the div would automatically be pushed down to the second line when the "finalized addresses" got wide enough to take up most of the line. Now that I think about it more, I guess what you'd really want would just be to have all of them to be inline, so your original plan of `<span>`s inserted before an `<input>` is probably the best/easiest option (all of the items are `display:inline` by default). GMail actually sets its "finalized address" `<span>`s to be `display:inline-block`, probably so they don't break lines.